# how do I replace a file input tag with a predetermined file?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to read a file line by line and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331546/how-to-use-javascript-to-read-local-text-file-and-read-line-by-line) to do it. the problem is, it has to use a file input tag to select the file to read, so I need to replace a file input tag with something that will let me pre-program a file in, this is the tag

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

(Please don't roast me if this is ridiculously obvious)

Comment: WAIT the tag - <input type="file" name="file" id="file">

Comment: If that was possible it would be a huge security hole, so don't count on that. What is the use case? Why do you need to pre-program a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the destination in the name

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="C:\Users\PC\Downloads\1.docx"\>
```

But of course like what abl said in the comment section. It will have a huge security hole because no user wants to have unwanted download of their files when submitting to your forms.