# Angular2: read file line by line

Tags: file, angular, filereader

I have an angular2 component that let user upload a file. This is how i read files when uploaded:
template:

```
<div>
  Select file:
  <input type="file" (change)="changeListener($event)" >
</div>
```

And changeListener code portion for read file:

```
 var reader:FileReader = new FileReader();
 reader.onloadend = function(e){
    console.log(reader.result);
 }
 reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0], 'ISO-8859-1');
```

In this way i'm able to read entire file, but i need to read line by line.
How can i do ?

Comment: Do you need to push each line to an array?

Comment: `result.split("\n")` will give you an array that you can loop each line. [Possible duplicate.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331546/how-to-use-javascript-to-read-local-text-file-and-read-line-by-line)