# How to store lines into array after loading a selected local file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load a text file and store lines within the text file into an array variable. I found a related issue but I want to enhance it furtheremore

```
<div>
  Select a text file:
  <input type="file" id="fileInput">
</div>
<pre id="displayFile"></pre>


<script>
   var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
   fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
          var file = fileInput.files[0];
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function(e) {
              document.getElementById('displayFile').innerText = reader.result;
              myAddress.push(reader.result)
      };
          reader.readAsText(file);
      });
</script>
```

and I want the lines that are read go into myAddress array

```
var myAddress = [];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Javascript to read local text file and read line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331546/how-to-use-javascript-to-read-local-text-file-and-read-line-by-line)

Comment: it is ! but i just want to figure out how to store those lines into array

Comment: `myAddress.push(line)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
   var myAddress = []
   fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
     var file = fileInput.files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e) {
       document.getElementById('displayFile').innerText = reader.result;
       myAddress = reader.result.split('\r\n')
     };
     reader.readAsText(file);
   });
```