# Insert textbox value of .txt file

Tags: javascript, html

I use the following code:

```
<td width='200'><input type='text' name='textbox' value='text of .txt file' id='myInput'>
```

How can I input the contents of a text box from the contents of a text file?
Patch text file: C:/textfile.txt

Comment: This is more or less not possible. You could look into having the user submit a file: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications or request file system access: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem

Comment: Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331546/how-to-use-javascript-to-read-local-text-file-and-read-line-by-line

Comment: Scenario. You visit my website, I read your root non-sandboxed level files into a hidden input on a form you submit for whatever reason and attach them to the payload I receive without your knowledge. How would you feel about that? ;)