# read text from file and keep in an array in

Tags: javascript

At the following code, I have the array of `["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]`.

```html
<div>
    <span id="my-element" class=" css-1yy09vp" data-font-weight="semibold"></span>
    <script>
        const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
        const textElement = document.getElementById("text");
        function carDisplayer() {
            let i = 0;
            return function(cars) {
                let interval = setInterval(() => {
                    if (i < cars.length) {
                        textElement.textContent = cars[i];
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }, 10000);
            }
        }
        let displayCars = carDisplayer();
        displayCars(cars);
    </script>
</div>
```

I am interested in reading the content of the array from a text file instead of hardcoding. For example, if I have the following file;

```
Saab
Volvo
BMW
```

called "content.txt", how can I read the content and assign it as "cars" array?

Thanks,

Comment: Client side javascript does not have access to the file system, do you want to read the file from user input or perhaps self hosted under some endpoint?

Comment: Is this your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331546/how-to-use-javascript-to-read-local-text-file-and-read-line-by-line

Comment: I am doing an experiment, I would like to run my code in localhost.

Comment: Yes @AmirrezaNoori, how can I apply that answer to my case?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Is it like a carousel where you're just rotating through the cars, and when you get to the end of the array looping back round?

Comment: Yes @Andy, exactly!

Comment: fetch the txt file, extract data and pass the data to the interval function

Answer (score 4):

There are many options. Easiest is to store the JSON as separate file and save it as JS. The file will look like

```
var data = [{...}, {...}];
```

You will only load the file with `<script src="./data.js"></script>`.

If you will store it as json then it's bit harder and you need to get it with ajax. Easiest is to use fetch(). You will get the file, parse it and save it.

```
fetch('./data.json').then(data => JSON.parse(data)).then(data => callback(data));
```

To handle the async call will be up to you if you want to use callback in some async call or what you will need. This will handle it in browser. As it looks like you are not doing any SSR.

You can change your code to something like this:

```
<script>
    const textElement = document.getElementById("text");
    function carDisplayer() {
        let i = 0;
        return function(cars) {
            let interval = setInterval(() => {
                if (i < cars.length) {
                    textElement.textContent = cars[i];
                    i++;
                } else {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    i = 0;
                }
            }, 10000);
        }
    }
    let displayCars = carDisplayer();
    fetch('./data.json').then(data => JSON.parse(data)).then(data => displayCars(data));
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @martin. After loading the file, how can I call it, or use it in my script? If you can mention that as well, that would be a great complete answer! Thanks!

Comment: @yusuf It was in original post, but I also added it for your name of the function.

Answer (score 2):

**1st option: Read online file**

Online files can be read through AJAX methods such as `XHR` or `fetch`. The following code could be a solution but it's not working for files on the computer. The `content.txt` file must be beside the HTML file on the server.

More information about fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
<div>
  <span id="my-element" class="css-1yy09vp" data-font-weight="semibold"></span>
  <script>
  let cars = [];
  const textElement = document.getElementById("my-element");
  function carDisplayer() {
    let i = 0;
    return function(cars) {
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (i < cars.length) {
           textElement.innerHTML = cars[i];
           i++;
        } else {
           clearInterval(interval);
           i = 0;
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  fetch("./content.txt").then(function(response) {
    response.text().then(function(text) {
      console.log(text);
      cars = text.split('\n');
      let displayCars = carDisplayer();
      displayCars(cars);
    });
  });       
  </script>
</div>
```

**2nd option: Read from user computer**

Reading a file from the user's computer is impossible until that user allows it.
In the following code, user should browse the `content.txt` file, then the code will run.

```
Select Text File: <input type="file" id="file-select">
<div>  
  <span id="my-element" class="css-1yy09vp" data-font-weight="semibold"></span>
  <script>
  let cars = [];
  const textElement = document.getElementById("my-element");
  function carDisplayer() {
    let i = 0;
    return function(cars) {
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (i < cars.length) {
           textElement.innerHTML = cars[i];
           i++;
        } else {
           clearInterval(interval);
           i = 0;
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById('file-select').onchange = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(progressEvent){    
      console.log(this.result);
      cars = this.result.split('\n');  
      let displayCars = carDisplayer();
      displayCars(cars);
    };
    reader.readAsText(this.files[0]);
  };
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using node.js. this could help you:

```
const readLine = require('readline');
const f = require('fs');
var file = './demo.txt';
var rl = readLine.createInterface({
    input : f.createReadStream(file),
    output : process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});
rl.on('line', function (text) {
 console.log(text);
});
```

### Outline:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Line 5
```

---

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not use node.js unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

fetch the txt file, extract data and pass the data to the interval function

```
      const textElement = document.getElementById("text");

      function carDisplayer(cars) {
        let i = 0;

          let interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (i < cars.length) {
              textElement.textContent = cars[i];
              i++;
            } else {
              clearInterval(interval);
              i = 0;
            }
          }, 10000);

      }


      fetch('/file.txt')
        .then(function(response) {
          response.text()
            .then(function(text) {
              console.log('res', text);
              let res = text.split('\n');
              cars = res;
              console.log(res);
              carDisplayer(res);
            });
        });
```