# Trying to reverse the text file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reverse

I am trying to reverse the text of my file as shown below.

**help.txt**
Hi my name is mitchell
This is my practice midterm
cheese pizza sucks
help me please

**The output should be:**
help me please
cheese pizza sucks
this is my practice midterm
Hi name is mitchell

**My output is:**
esaelp em pleh
skcus azzip eseehc
mretdim ecitcarp ym si sihT
llehctim si eman ym iH

Here is my code

```js
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('help.txt', function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var array = data.toString().split("\n");
    for(i in array) {
        console.log(array[i]);
    }
    const reversed = array.reverse();
    console.log('reversed:', reversed);

    fs.writeFile('Output.txt', data.reverse(), (err) => {
      
    // In case of an error throw err.
    if (err) throw err;
});
});
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is why is the text reversing on a per line basis, when I am trying to get the whole line to reverse order.

Comment: Why do you do `fs.writeFile('Output.txt', data.reverse()` instead of `fs.writeFile('Output.txt', reversed`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you're looking for is found in the [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline) module.

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71983228/20313186) from [@Ark-kun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497385/ark-kun) demonstrates well how to implement the module. As noted in that answer, the method to read a file line-by-line is not as trivial as it may first seem.

Your scenario is slightly different from the questioned linked above, but I wanted to still highlight it for reference.

The solution for your question would be:

```js
/* Import Node Modules */
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");

/*
* Function to process line by line.
* This example is taken from the docs and modified
* for your scenario.
*/
async function processLineByLine() {
 /* Read stream and interface */
 const inputStream = fs.createReadStream("./test.txt");
 const lineReader = readline.createInterface({
   input: inputStream,
   terminal: false,
 });

 /* Push each line to a new array. */
 const results = [];
 for await (const line of lineReader) {
   results.push(line);
 }

 /* Return a new array, reversed. */
 return results.reverse();
}

/* Do something with the result. */
processLineByLine().then(res => console.log(res));
```

For more information, the following may be useful:

- [Node.js Docs - readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline)
- [W3 Schools on readline](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/ref_readline.asp)

Comment: Hello @TSxo, this works for reading, but it doesn't reverse the lines of the text file.

Comment: Hi there @Mitchell, my apologies for not including an example. I updated my answer with an example of how to implement it asynchronously and reverse the array. Let me know if that makes things a more clear :)