# How to read a file and convert to json array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

If I have a file like below:

```
key1 key2
data1 data2
data3 data4
...
```

Is there an easy way to read this file and convert it to a json object array?
The final output I want is :

```
[{key1:data1, key2: data2},{key1: data3, key2: data4}, ...]
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "json array": build a normal JS array, and then if you need the JSON string representation of that, you juse use`JSON.stringify`. So your question is about how to turn that data into JS, not into JSON (the JSON part is essentially an irrelevant last step =). So: what have you tried already to load in that data, and then turn that into a normal array of plain JS objects?

Comment: This looks like a kind of space separated values file. There are many parsers out there (most CSV ones offer a `delimiter` option). If you are not the one producing these files, I'd highly recommend you to use such a parser. Files in the wild come with a lot of weirdnesses that are hard to handle, e.g. for basic ones, could `data1` itself contain a space? Is it supposed to be escaped with a `\` character or is the whole value supposed to be inside `"` quotes? Same for new line characters, and btw. which new line feed are you expecting? LF? CRLF? a mix? And I don't even touch encodings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import fs from 'fs';

// read the file and split into rows and cells
const data = fs.readFileSync('./text.txt').toString().split('\n').map(row => row.match(/\w+/g));
// get the first row with cells as key names
const head = data.shift();

// map the rest of the rows into objects with keys from the first row
const result = data.map(row => Object.fromEntries(row.map((cell, idx) => [head[idx], cell])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

The result:

```
/usr/local/bin/node ./read-csv.mjs
[{"key1":"data1","key2":"data2"},{"key1":"data3","key2":"data4"}]
```

If you need some speed boost with a big file, use `Array::reduce()`:

```
import fs from 'fs';

const data = fs.readFileSync('./text.txt').toString().split('\n').map(row => row.match(/\w+/g));
const head = data.shift();

const result = data.map(row => row.reduce((obj, cell, idx) => {
    obj[head[idx]] = cell;
    return obj;
}, {}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

If you need the maximum speed use `for` loops:

```
import fs from 'fs';

const data = fs.readFileSync('./text.txt').toString().split('\n').map(row => row.match(/\w+/g));
const head = data.shift();

const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const row = data[i];
    const item = result[result.length] = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        item[head[j]] = row[j];
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Vanilla Javascript or NodeJS? Node has the package `fs` which has got utility functions to perform filesystem operations.

Irrespective of whether you are using Node or Vanilla JS, you could consider the following approach.

```
Read the file into a variable(not adding the code for that here as the method will vary depending on whether you are using Node or Vanilla JS), say fileContent

let lines = fileContent.split("\n");

const result = [];

lines.forEach(line => {
  let dataValues = line.split(" "); //Assuming the values are separated by space
  result.push({key1: dataValues[0], key2: dataValues[1]});
});
```

`result` will hold the required output.

Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331546/how-to-use-javascript-to-read-local-text-file-and-read-line-by-line) that might be useful for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This python code will do it for you

```
import json

def convert_file_to_json(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    
    # Extract keys from the first line
    keys = lines[0].split()

    # Create JSON object array
    json_objects = []
    for line in lines[1:]:
        values = line.split()
        json_object = {keys[i]: values[i] for i in range(len(keys))}
        json_objects.append(json_object)

    return json.dumps(json_objects)

# Usage example
filename = 'your_file.txt'
json_data = convert_file_to_json(filename)
print(json_data)
```

Comment: How is this an answer to a JavaScript question?